# Is the King James Bible banned in China?

Tags: bible, bible-translation, law, persecution, china

I understand there are state-sanctioned churches in China, but that implies that Bibles in China are edited by the CCP.

Would an Anglican Bible be legal, or at least easy, to bring into China?

Comment: law SE would probably be a better place to ask this sort of question

Comment: The question can be improved to elicit a **documented** answer for these related concerns: 1) what can be brought in (cursory search shows only up to 3 *personal* copies can be brought in); 2) official ways to bring in Bible for distribution through "registered" churches; 3) the [10-year project for CCP-approved translation](https://premierchristian.news/en/news/article/china-is-rewriting-the-bible-with-communist-principles-says-christian-watchdog), making the answer a moving target; 4) whether there are restrictions on specific translations, both in Mandarin or in Western languages.

Comment: this is an informative question...i had no idea that the Chinese government was rewriting a sympathetic paraphrase that grossly misrepresents the real scriptures. i think it too important to move outside of Christianity as those who should know about this may never visit the other forum and find it. perhaps reword question to make it on topic for this forum.

Comment: This link [Bitter Winter .org](https://bitterwinter.org/how-xi-jinping-became-god/) catalogues efforts by the Chinese Government and the Communist Party to sideline all religion and to propagate a culture of worship of Xi Jinping instead.

Comment: Asking about bringing Bibles when visiting China on [Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tour) might provide answers with personal experiences.

Answer (score 6):

***Q – Is the King James Bible banned in China?***

A – It would seem that the King James Bible is not banned - yet.

However, as part of a longstanding effort to limit the influence of Christianity in China, central government authorities last year indicated that they would publish an “official translation” of the Bible for Chinese worshippers.  The CCP called for “a comprehensive evaluation of the existing religious classics aiming at contents which do not conform to the progress of the times” in a 2019 meeting held by the Committee for Ethnic and Religious Affairs, which oversees religious matters in China.  The meeting concluded that the new “official edition” of the Bible must not contain any content that contradicts socialism, and paragraphs deemed wrong by censors will be amended or retranslated.  Source: https://www.voanews.com/a/east-asia-pacific_china-conducts-two-trials-crackdown-audio-bibles/6199571.html

***Q – Would an Anglican Bible be legal, or at least easy, to bring into China?***

A – January 2023: Bibles are allowed for personal use and up to three copies is a reasonable number. Any extra copies will be confiscated by Customs.  Source: https://www.travelchinaguide.com/essential/not-taken.htm

Be aware that the Chinese government is currently rewriting the Bible to align it with Communist principles and values.  The new “official edition” of the Bible must not contain any content that contradicts socialism, and paragraphs deemed wrong by censors will be amended or retranslated.  Source: https://www.voanews.com/a/east-asia-pacific_china-conducts-two-trials-crackdown-audio-bibles/6199571.html

In a recent Facebook post, VOM shared an example of several verses in John 8 changed according to the Chinese government. As the biblical story goes, Jesus forgives an adulterous woman despite the Pharisees' calls to stone her to death. However, in the CCP's translation, Jesus ends up stoning the woman, admitting he is also a sinner.  John 8:7-11, according to the CCP reads: "Jesus once said to the angry crowd who was trying to stone a woman who had sinned, 'He who is without sin among you, let him cast a stone at her.' When his words came to their ears, they stopped moving forward. When everyone went out, Jesus stoned the woman himself, and said, 'I am also a sinner.'"

Nettleton told FaithWire he thought the rewritten passage was trying to diminish Jesus' divinity.  He said: "If Jesus is a sinner, then he's not God."  "The issue for the Chinese Communist Party is control. It is always about control," Nettleton added.  "And they see the … Christian message as something that would take control away from the communist party."   Source: https://premierchristian.news/en/news/article/china-is-rewriting-the-bible-with-communist-principles-says-christian-watchdog

With thanks to Grateful Disciple and Nigel J for two the links provided.

Comment: +1  Interesting to learn about the rewriting of the Bible. please keep it updated when you heard of anything new.. Do you have the link to "a recent Facebook post"?